# Bernoulli distributed random variables - Change point Detection

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, change-point

I am looking for change point detector model for my Bernoulli random variable. I built my simple detector, the absolute difference between stander deviation of of all transaction history stored, and recent transactions, large absolute difference represent behavior change, but I am not that confident to go with. However, I have found an article that explained The log-likelihood ratio in [http://www.claudiobellei.com/2016/11/15/changepoint-frequentist/]

The Bernoulli distribution is possibly the easiest distribution of all. It models binary events that have probability 
p
 of happening and probability 
1
−
p
 of not happening. This is why it is usually introduced in probability theory with the “coin flipping” example.

As before, we can write the likelihood under the null hypothesis

$\begin{equation}
\mathcal L_{H_0} = p_0^m(1-p_0)^{N-m}
\end{equation}$

and under the alternative hypothesis,

$\begin{equation}
\mathcal L_{H_1} = p_1^{m_1}(1-p_1)^{\tau-m_1}p_2^{m_2}(1-p_2)^{N-\tau-m_2} .
\end{equation}$

The log-likelihood ratio becomes

$\bbox[white,5px,border:2px solid red]{
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{R}_\tau=\log\left(\frac{\mathcal{L}_{H_1}}{\mathcal{L}_{H_0}}\right) = & \hspace{-2cm} m_1\log(p_1) + (\tau-m_1)\log(1-p_1) + m_2\log(p_2) \nonumber \\
&  + (N-\tau-m_2)\log(1-p_2) - m\log p_0 - (N-m)\log(1-p_0) \hspace{1.5cm}
\label{eq:LR3}
\end{eqnarray}
}$

What does $p_1, m_1, p_2, m_2$ represent, and more importantly $\tau$. And how change point is detected.

Comment: This 'test' depends on $\tau$, i.e. it is not a quantity that you can simply compute but rather you give it some $\tau$ and it returns a value (confidence) of 'how much more' it thinks that $H_1$ is true than $H_0$. $\tau$ (an integer between 1 and $N-1$) represents the changepoint that splits the dataset into two parts, $m_1$ represents the $+1$-entries inthe first part (before the changepoint), $m_2$ represents the amount of $+1$entries in the second part (after the changepoint) and $p_1$ is the parameter on the first part and $p_2$ is the parameter on the second part and changepoint means

Comment: that $p_1$ changes to some significally different value $p_2$

Comment: I guess that you just try different values for $\tau$ and see whether you get a sufficiently high value for the log likelihood stuff... that it like a confidence level in a normal t-test. If you get some value $\tau$ for which the log likelihood value is so high that you define it to be 'realistic' then you have found the (first?) changepoint $\tau$. You could also try to maximize this log likelihood expression with some kind of optimization (gradient ascend for example) and see whether the maximal value is 'high' enough for you to believe in

Comment: I like the idea of maximizing it.. thank you. $p$ is probability here or parameter

Comment: @FabianWerner, is it logically right to do optimization such as maximize SD value of my simple detector ,I mentioned in the post, with gradient ascend.